# Get friendly url of parent page through TypoScript for the body tag

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I overwrite my body object through TypoScript like this:

```
page.bodyTagCObject.dataWrap = <body id="p{field:uid}" data-pid="p{field:pid}">
```

Now I would be interested to provide a data-xxx parameter to the body tag that contains the friendly url (EXT:realurl used) of the parent page.

Is there an easy way through TypoScript to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build the link and then wrap it.
In TYPO3 nearly everywhere you can use `.stdWrap` or `.cObject`. So you can wrap a wrap. Use this as inspiration:

```
page.bodyTagCObject.wrap {
    cObject = TEXT
    cObject.typolink {
        parameter.field = pid
        returnLast = url
    }
    dataWrap = <body id="p{field:uid}" data-pid="p{field:pid}" data-url="|" >
}
```